# How can I get some text from data uri and assign to an array?

Tags: php, data-uri

my data

> this1
>
> this2
>
> this3
>
> this4

what I want

```
$keepit[0]='this1';
$keepit[1]='this2';
$keepit[2]='this3';
$keepit[3]='this4';
```

data uri

data:text/plain;charset=utf-8;base64,dGhpczENCnRoaXMyDQp0aGlzMw0KdGhpczQ=

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with normal file methods using the [data://](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.data.php) protocol:

```
$data = file('data://text/plain;charset=utf-8;base64,dGhpczENCnRoaXMyDQp0aGlzMw0KdGhpczQ=');
```

Alternatively though you can pull out the base64 encoded string and decode it yourself:

```
$plaintext = base64_decode('dGhpczENCnRoaXMyDQp0aGlzMw0KdGhpczQ=');
```

Comment: 'file_get_contents','file','base64_decode'   ... what is the best solution ?

Comment: The best option depends on your use case. If you are accepting data encoded files that may vary in encoding then the `data://` protocol is probably safest. If you're always just accepting plaintext base64 then `base64_decode` will likely be fastest, you will then need to explode the string it returns in to an array.

Answer (score 0):

If the encoded string can be decoded this will work:

```
$file_path = ''; // change this.
$fp = fopen($file_path, 'rb');
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($file_path));
fclose($fp);
$data_uri = preg_split('/,/', $contents);
$encoded = $data_uri[1];
$decoded = base64_decode($encoded);
var_dump($decoded);
```